# Existence of function with conditions on derivatives and anti-derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

How does one find functions that satisfy the following properties:

$$f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$$

and

$$f^{(n)}(-1)=f^{(n)}(1)=0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb Z$$

Does such functions exist?

I'm sorry for any mistaken notation since I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: If you mean for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, yes; look up [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).

Comment: I also wonder if such functions exist when $n$ is a negative integer

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) =e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$$ for $x\in (-1,1)$ and $f(x) =0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus (-1,1).$

Comment: Does this also work for the anti-derivative?